# Where can I find the non-retina iPhone Simulator running iOS 7.0 in Xcode 5?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios7, xcode5

Where can I find the non-retina iPhone Simulator running iOS 7.0 in Xcode 5?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no iOS 7 non-retina iPhone simulator as iOS 7 is only supported by retina iPhones. If you want the non-retina because of screen space you can use Window -> Scale -> 75% or 50%.

Comment: Guess the interesting question here is what happens with iPhone apps run on an iPad2 - which is the only non-retina device remaining supported.

Comment: That and the iPad mini. They use the retina assets and always run in the old 2x mode. If you try to run existing iPhone apps on the non-retina iPad on iOS 7 they look a lot better than they used to. So, if you are developing iOS 7 only iPhone apps most of the 1x assets are no longer needed.

Comment: I'm developing apps for the non retina ipad2 with ios7 and would like the simulator for it... but looks like it's one of those apple "ignore our users" things they are reknowned for

Comment: That simulator is there, it is just called iPad and supports iOS 6.0, 6.1 and 7.0.

Comment: I want the bezels around simulator (even without high-resolution display). It was so cute, and now it is gone.

Comment: I think you get it back if you have a retina MacBook Pro ;)

Comment: The bezels will only show if the simulator view will fit onto your screen without chopping off any of it vertically and horizontally. I have a 27 inch iMac and the simulator shows the bazels perfectly on a 4 inch iPhone (retina), the moment I drag it onto another smaller screen and then rotate the simulator- the bezels go away. So as hypercrypt mentioned, increase resolution to get more space if you have a retina macBook

Comment: @hypercrypt: Running my iPhone app on the iPad simulator (not the iPad Retina or iPad Retina 64-bit) still gives a `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` value of 2.

Comment: @trss: Yes, if you look at my earlier comment: "They use the retina assets and always run in the old 2x mode... So, if you are developing iOS 7 only iPhone apps most of the 1x assets are no longer needed". There is no screen scale of 1 any more for iPhone apps on iOS 7 (except for external displays).